# How do i write this Ranking formula?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, epplus, epplus-4

I have a worksheet as shown in the attached image. I want to perform ranking for each position cell based on the corresponding Term (FirstTerm, Second, Third, Annual). I have tried but cant figure a way to write the formula. I am using EPPlus

I already tried using C# to compute it but the Total and Average columns are using formulas and run when it gets to the client.

[Work Sheet Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-EaUAQOraRQV2ZjTXVmcG45ak0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: what have you tried already? what is your first column, the one before TERM column?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel you can rank using COUNTIF function so for ranking with a condition (like here) you can use COUNTIFS. If you want to rank the totals column within each term try this formula in row 2 copied down

> =COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,N:N,">"&N2)+1

that only gives you a number like 1, 2 etc. Do you need. 1st, 2nd etc.?